# SQL, The logic for grouping

Tags: sql

The SQL is executed without issue. The question is HOW the result is grouped all courses in one line for each person?  Or how the SQL is executed step by step?

```
select name,
(select 'o' from Courses where name = c.name and course = 'SQL')as SQL,
(select 'o' from Courses where name = c.name and course = 'UNIX')as UNIX,
(select 'o' from Courses where name = c.name and course = 'Java')as Java
from Courses c
group by name
```

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE Courses
(name   VARCHAR(32), 
 course VARCHAR(32), 
 PRIMARY KEY(name, course));

INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Tom', 'SQL');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Tom', 'UNIX');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Jack', 'SQL');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Mike', 'SQL');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Mike', 'Java');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Jane', 'UNIX');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Mary', 'SQL');
```

Comment: Actual execution order (Step by step) is decided by the optimizer. Logical evaluation order is FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, SELECT, ORDER BY, OFFSET/FETCH.

Comment: BTW, no need for subqueries here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row in the outer query, an inner subquery is checking if a certain course exists for a given person.  This approach will only work if the subqueries will always return at most one record.  Also, your query will only run on databases like MySQL which tolerate non ANSI compliant `GROUP BY` behavior.  Otherwise, your query would result in an error.

Here is a more canonical way of doing this via conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN course = 'SQL' THEN 1 END) > 0  THEN 'o' END AS SQL,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN course = 'UNIX' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'o' END AS UNIX,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN course = 'Java' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'o' END AS Java
FROM Courses
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: How is the canonical way SQL executed regarding to outter query/inner query?  Can it be describe in steps, like, 1) taking one line from Courses 2)  executing query, CASE WHEN course = 'SQL' THEN 1 END  What's would be in step 3)? Thanks.

Comment: Other than MySQL and maybe a few other databases, your current query will result in error.  You should use my version as a valid option.

Comment: I've tested another SQL based on your version, the result lines are completely ungrounped.  What's the root difference, no more inner queries in it?  Really want to get it cleared. Thanks.  `SELECT  name,
       CASE WHEN course = 'SQL' THEN 'o' ELSE NULL END s,
       CASE WHEN course = 'UNIX' THEN 'o' ELSE NULL END u,
       CASE WHEN course = 'Java' THEN 'o' ELSE NULL END j
FROM Courses
GROUP BY name,course;`

Comment: I cannot fully explain aggregation in SQL using a small comment like this.

Comment: I have created another thread for this question. Please help on it. Anyway, got the outer query and inner query tips. Thanks.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124504/sql-what-aggregation-logic-makes-different-results