# SQL, what aggregation logic makes different results?

Tags: sql

SQL1 returns lines with aggreated names while SQL2 returns the non-aggreated.

Question is what's the difference of aggregation logic when executing the two SQLs. Thanks.

SQL1

```
SELECT
    name,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN course = 'SQL' THEN 1 END) > 0  THEN 'o' END AS SQL,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN course = 'UNIX' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'o' END AS UNIX,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN course = 'Java' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'o' END AS Java
FROM Courses
GROUP BY name;
```

SQL2

```
SELECT  name,
       CASE WHEN course = 'SQL' THEN '○' ELSE NULL END s,
       CASE WHEN course = 'UNIX' THEN '○' ELSE NULL END u,
       CASE WHEN course = 'Java' THEN '○' ELSE NULL END j
FROM Courses
GROUP BY name,course;
```

Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE Courses
(name   VARCHAR(32), 
 course VARCHAR(32), 
 PRIMARY KEY(name, course));

INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Tom', 'SQL');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Tom', 'UNIX');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Jack', 'SQL');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Mike', 'SQL');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Mike', 'Java');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Jane', 'UNIX');
INSERT INTO Courses VALUES('Mary', 'SQL');
```

Comment: If you execute the queries, you'll see the difference. BTW, GROUP BY without any aggregate functions is a bit strange.

Comment: I would say that difference in logic is obvious, in first query you group by just name (basically you are saying group all rows with same name as one row) in second you group by name and course (basically, all rows with same name and same course should be one row)

Comment: Hi, @Aarlaneth, cool ! I've thought it is some high level skills, instead it is the "merit" of “group by”.  You solved my other questions. Please reply instead of comment so that I can conclude the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that difference in logic is obvious, in first query you group by just name.

```
GROUP BY name
```

Basically, you are saying group all rows with same name as one row.

In second query you group by name and course.

```
GROUP BY name,course
```

Which means, all rows with same name and same course should be one row.